# Retrieving User Name from Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, iprincipal

I am trying to retrieve the User Name from Active Directory. I have found this piece of code to try however, it does not recognize the `User` portion of `User.Identity.Name`. I have looked to see if I need to add another reference or assembly however I have not seen anything.  Is there a better way of getting the User Name from Active Directory?

```
static string GetUserName(){

        string name = "";
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            var usr = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
            if (usr != null)
                name = usr.DisplayName;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent**

```
using System.Security.Principal;

static string GetUserName()
{
    WindowsIdentity wi = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

    string[] parts = wi.Name.Split('\\');

    if(parts.Length > 1) //If you are under a domain
        return parts[1];
    else
        return wi.Name;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string fullName = GetUserName();
```

Happy to help you!

Comment: For some reason when I try this the `wi` in `wi.Name.Split` is not recognized

Comment: Are you referencing "using System.Security.Principal;"?

Comment: yes I am reference it. It say - a field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'OpenBurn.Controllers.RequestBurnsController.wi'

Comment: Please post your entire class. Error is on another point of code.

Comment: How would I call GetUserName() to get wi.Name in my controller?

Comment: Just call GetUserName() and get the username.

Comment: when I do that I get a message saying that "Method Must have a return Type". I thought I might be doing something wrong

Comment: your method return a string and you forgot to return... you never returned. [**Add "return name;" to your code.**]

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public string GetUserName()
{
    string name = "";

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var usr = UserPrincipal.Current;

        if (usr != null)
        {
            name = usr.DisplayName;
        }
    }
}
```